# Tablesorter (mottie fork) condinionally multi-column sort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

friendly coders :-) 
   I need in rather basic functionality of tablesorter jquery plugin. First of all, I don't need in table pre-sort. I display the table inititally strictly in the order as data are in the file.
   So, right now my code is VERY simple and is the following one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#results").tablesorter({
        cancelSelection: true,
        headers:
            {  0 : { sorter: "text" },
               1 : { sorter: "digit" },
               2 : { sorter: "text" },
               3 : { sorter: "digit" },
               3 : { sortInitialOrder: "desc" },
               4 : { sorter: "digit" },
               4 : { sortInitialOrder: "desc" }
            }
                              });
     } 
); 
    $('#results').on('sortBegin', function () {
         var c = this.config,
         col = c.sortList[0][0];
          if ( col === 0 ) {
// column 0 sorting, add column 2
               c.sortList.push( [2,0] );
   } else if ( col === 2 ) {
// column 2 sorting, add column 4
        c.sortList.push( [4,1] );
    }
}).tablesorter({
    widgets: ['columns']
});
</script>
```

What I need: 
1. sort by column 0 (ascending, default), then column 2 (ascending, default)
2. sort by column 2 (ascending, default), then column 4 (ascending, non-default)

I don't want to use sortAppend because I don't want ALWAYS make some additional sorting. I need in it ONLY for columns 0 and 2.
I don't want to use widgets with "secondary" and "thertiary" options because of I don't want to make "secondary" sorting.
Really I need in something like conditional sortappend, like

```
sortAppend [0]: [2,0]
sortAppend [2]: [4,1]
```

How can I do it?

**Upd**: I changed the basic question to include the proposed solutions. It's tested and working as required, many thanks to Mottie and his fork of tablesorter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you can bind to the `sortBegin` event and append the custom sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/678/))

```
$(function () {
    $('table').on('sortBegin', function () {
        var c = this.config,
            col = c.sortList[0][0];
        if ( col === 0 ) {
            // column 0 sorting, add column 2
            c.sortList.push( [2,0] );
        } else if ( col === 2 ) {
            // column 2 sorting, add column 4
            c.sortList.push( [4,1] );
        }
    }).tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, implemented in my code and already tested! It would be wise probably to include this example to documentation and/or examples at github to prevent the asking for this feature again and again. Really it is strongly required feature for all non-commercial-database-like tables (statistics, science etc).

Comment: You can now reference a column in the `sortAppend` option (e.g. `sortAppend: { 0 : [[2,0]], 2 : [[4,1]] }`. This change is currently available in the master branch ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/commit/b8e2b65493e4777275bf18a53ce9152a884ae8ff#diff-4)) - official update coming soon.